# I want to update my frame and piechart on button click

Tags: python, tkinter, pie-chart

I am using python tkinter to make my GUI .

1) I have 3 Frames, 1st frame has 3 buttons and the output of these buttons is show on 2nd frame but when I select 1st button the output of first button is shown on the second frame and then when the second button is pressed the output of both the button merges and showed on second frame. I want to update my frame on button click.

2) 3rd frame shows me the output of 2nd frame means when I enter my entry in second frame and press submit button a pie chart is drawn on the 3rd frame but when I select next entry on my 2nd frame and press submit the pie chart doesn't update. I want my piechart to be updated with every click.

Comment: I think Priyanshu agarwal is trying to say that the outputs of the button functions should be displayed once he presses these buttons. But if he presses just one button Nothing happens. He has to press the second button, then the Outputs are displayed. There is an easy way to solve that. (Read my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code at the bottom of every function that you use for the buttons:

```
root.update()  # where root is your tkinter window
```

Comment: No its not throwing an error but it is not updating my frame and it is not clearing the piechart.

Comment: Make sure add `root.update()` in every function you have. It should work.